# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null - For Countdown Script

Tags: javascript, timer, typeerror, countdown, innertext

I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null error message in my console where the errors just keep rising indefinitely. It is related to a script I have running to countdown to a particular set of dates.

I have attempted removing the script which removes the error. Aside from that I am not sure exactly where it's going wrong. Aside from something to do with the `target.innerText = "Expired"` line.

```
"use strict";

timer = function timer(target, date) {
  var target = document.querySelector(target);
  var countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();
  setInterval(function () {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
    target.innerText = days;

    if (distance < 0) {
      target.innerText = "Expired";
     }
  }, 1000);
};

timer("#timer1", "Jan 01, 2019 11:59:59");
timer("#timer2", "Jan 02, 2019 11:59:59");
timer("#timer3", "Jan 03, 2019 11:59:59");
```

Any and all help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

edit:

Here is a section of the html

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="dates-container">
  <div class="dates-wrapper">
    <p class="date"><strong>Jan 01</strong> <span class="days-remaining"><span id="timer1"></span> Days Remaining</span></p>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="upcoming-dates">
   <p class="date"><strong>Jan 02</strong> <span class="days-rem"> . <span id="timer2"></span> Days Remaining</span></p>
   <div class="divider"></div>
  </div>               
 </div>
</div>
```

It works on the main index.html and I am trying to add the countdowns to a different page by giving the elements and ID of "timerX" - the errors didnt show up until I added the countdowns to the second page.

Thanks again for the help, I feel like I am overlooking something simple but I dont know.

Comment: That means `document.querySelector()` isn't finding the element you want to put the timer on.

Comment: It's not the problem, but shouldn't you clear the timer when it reaches 0?

Comment: Could you also show a snippet of your HTML? It looks like there are no elements with either id "timer1", "timer2" or "timer3", so `document.querySelector(target)` will return and assign a null value to `target`

Comment: @Nicolás Marzano I edited the main post to include a snippet of the html, let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
var target = document.querySelector(target);
```

is definitely setting `var target` to null.
So that`s exactly what the interpreter is telling you.

I assume it can't find `#timer3`.

Comment: Funny you say that, so as soon as I remove #timer3 from the list in the js script, the console errors disappear. So what is #timer3 causing an issue and say #timer2 is not? Sorry I am just trying to understand the issue.

Comment: So here is the Problem:
You are caling your function 3 times:

timer("#timer1", "Jan 01, 2019 11:59:59");
timer("#timer2", "Jan 02, 2019 11:59:59");
timer("#timer3", "Jan 03, 2019 11:59:59");

one time, with argument "#timer3"

but you dont have timer3 specified in your html file, so thats why the selector can`t find it

Comment: ah, well, don't have an excuse for that one! Thank you for that! Quick follow up, if I have #timer3 set in the script but let's say I don't use it on my index.html but use it on page2.html would that still cause issues as it's not being called up in index.html?

Comment: @GideonB as soon as you call your script and the script can't find the HTML element you will get an error. Wheter you get the error or not will depend on how you include your script to your HTML file. 

if page2.html has all 3 components timer1, timer2 and timer3 the script won't throw an error when included to your page2.html page. but it will throw an error when included on other pages, that don't have all 3 elements. Im glad i could help